# combine two FOR LOOPS (MakeFeatureLayer_management)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I want to combine two FOR LOOPS but I have no idea how.
It should give me in each  TYPE Layer "under" Layers, where are new Layers for each MONTH (see picture)

[image]

The two loops in itself works.

```
# MakeFeatureLayer_management for each whale/dolphin type
whale_names = [
"Atlantic Spotted Dolphin",
"Pilot Whale",
"Bottlenose Dolphin",
"Rough-Toothed Dolphin",
"Bryde´s Whale",
"Common Dolphin"]

 for name in whale_names:
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Sichtungen95-14", "test-" + name, "SPECIES = '%s'" % (name))
     # MakeFeatureLayer_management for each month
 for month in range (01,12):          
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("Sichtungen95-14", "test%s" % month, "DATE >= date'01.01.1995' AND DATE < date'01.01.2015' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) = %s" % (month))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply indent your second `for` loop, and it will iterate the twelve months for each iteration of your initial loop.

```
for name in whale_names:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Sichtungen95-14", "test-" + name, "SPECIES = '%s'" % (name))
    # MakeFeatureLayer_management for each month
    for month in range (01,12):          
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("Sichtungen95-14", "test%s" % month, "DATE >= date'01.01.1995' AND DATE < date'01.01.2015' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) = %s" % (month))
```